# How can we use marketo SDK with Marshmallow (API 23) when using proguard?

Tags: android, marketo

I have added the Marketo android SDK to our app.  When minifying the app through ProGuard, I notice that the app is now failing to build as it using a deprecated android method:

Warning:marketo.push.a: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification

I'd rather not target an android SDK below 23.  Has anyone encountered this problem and worked around it?

Comment: I tried it, MarketoSDK were using Notification class directly but Android restricts to use Notification.Builder above honeycomb. But try latest version of SDK. It's already fixed in latest version.

Comment: what's the marketosdk version ? I am not seeing it in latest version 0.5.1

Comment: This is fixed in the latest version soon after I added an issue on GitHub.  The guys at marketo listen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, think i've figured this out now.  Adding

```
-dontwarn android.app.Notification
```

to my pro-guard file appears to have solved the issue.  I cant check that its working end-to-end at the moment though.  If adding this causes no ill effects, i'll update this.